# Luabridge: heap corruption (_CrtIsValidHeapPointer) on remove

Tags: c++, c++11, lua, luabridge

Edit #3:

My engine is setup in the following manner:

```
struct Engine {
    GetEngine()....//Singleton;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DisplayObject>> DisplayObjects;
};
```

Then I write a few lua interfaces in the following manner:

```
 struct LuaObject {
    DisplayObject* ControlObject;
    void Initialize() { 
         auto NewObject=make_unique<DisplayObject>();
         Engine::GetEngine().DisplayObjects.push_back(std::move(NewObject));
         ControlObject=Engine::GetEngine().DisplayObjects.back().get();
    }
    void RemoveDisplayObject() {
        //we remove all objects just for a demonstration
        Engine::GetEngine().DisplayObjects.clear();
    }
};
```

The game loop in Engine will loop through DisplayObject and perform various tasks. When LUA calls RemoveDisplayObject() _CrtIsValidHeapPointer occurs.

We are removing items that are outside of LUA object, is this causing the problem?

What can cause a heap error? Should I approach this differently?

---

Here is the Logic in the engine:

**Game (Singleton)**

Contains `DisplayObjects` (vector of `DisplayObject`)

**Lua Bound Class:**

Calls `Game::Singleton` `CreateDisplayObject`, gets pointer to last object in `DisplayObjects`

Has `Remove()` function which calls `Game::Singleton` `RemoveDisplayObject` and passes the pointer from `CreateDisplayObject` <---- **This causes heap corruption (when calling vector.clear()). So removing items from vector is causing the heap error.**

Has some extra functions which work with the `DisplayObject` like moving it around, no heap corruption.

**Lua:**

Another class to wraps the Lua bound class

Contains `Remove()` function which calls **Lua Bound Class Remove()**

At one point the engine will load an extra lua file which calls Remove() on the lua class.

Comment: How is the memory allocated for the individual `DisplayObject`s? Can you add then code that allocates and inserts a new entry into `DisplayObjects`? When changed to a raw pointer the `clear()` will not `delete` them resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: show us your binding code as well

Comment: I think the issue is with binding, not Lua itself and/or pointer type.

Comment: You might consider using another binding. Point is, binding whole classes like that is quite limited. (I am not advocating, not at all! As a proof, I am not recommending any in particular).

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way it makes it completely different. If you want to ask another question, ask another question. Also SO is not going to debug the code for you.

Comment: All of the ControlObject pointers are suspiciously left dangling after the vector is cleared in RemoveDisplayObject() - what are you doing with ControlObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Luabridge's Readme:

> **Not supported:**
>
> - Standard containers like `std::shared_ptr`. *(sic!)*

So most probably, the fact you are using `unique_ptr` is totally destroying it. I recommends switching to some other binding library; or even writing something simple yourself.

Comment: Is there no _extension point_ / _customization hook_ / _derefence trait_ for this?! o.O

Comment: I've tried it with raw pointers and the same issue happens, heap corruption when removing an object. I've tried to reproduce this error with smaller code but it works fine. My binding code is quite large now so it could be something else... I just can't my finger on it.

Comment: While I am actively working on one such project myself, [Lundi](https://github.com/lundiorg/lundi) is currently a bit unstable, but you might want to give it a shot anyway (yes, it's tested!). And before someone flags that, disclaimer: It's an open source project, I get absolutely no revenue from that and do it in my free time. I honestly think it can help the OP. If that's still not ok with you, please drop a comment.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it on simpler code, @Grapes, try to gradually remove the code until you find the bit that really causes the problems.

Comment: I restructured my logic and simplified delete logic. No more heap errors! It had something to do with re-assigning variables C++ variables and re-redefining functions. The actual error still eludes me but at least I don't get heap errors anymore.